# Black screen after switching session

Tags: 14.04, users, session

I’m experiencing a black screen/block in this situation:

- user A begins a session
- switch to user B
- return to user A:---black screen---

No possibility of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>.

Can anybody help me?